# Using debounce in rxjs client side webapp

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am moving into functional reactive code starting with rxjs and have some questions about how to best import it as I am getting mixed results.

Currently, I have a simple implementation where I check a web service for if a username already exists.

Here is the code that works perfectly:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // setup an observable
    submission = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#submitbutton"), "click").map(
        event => {
            return "justsomeusername";
        }
    );

    submission
        .concatMap(username => {
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
                $.get(
                    "{{ site.serveraddress }}/checkuser?&username=" + username
                )
            ).catch(() => Rx.Observable.empty());
        })
        .subscribe(rval => {
            console.log(rval);
        });
});
```

This all works great BUT when I try to add a debounce like submission.debounce(500).concatMap((username) =>

```
Rx.js:8512 Uncaught TypeError: this.durationSelector.call is not a function
at DebounceSubscriber._next (Rx.js:8512)
at DebounceSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Rx.js:424)
at MapSubscriber._next (Rx.js:5715)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Rx.js:424)
at HTMLButtonElement.handler (Rx.js:3913)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

That is what appears in the console.

I think that the way I am importing or referencing the library is the cause, this is where there is some confusion.

I am importing like this at the top of an HTML page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.6/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

If I try to import any other reference the Rx object seems not to exist?  Does this have to do with the filename maybe becoming the object namespace?

For example, I downloaded all the latest rxjs release and in the dist see rx.all.js but if I import locally one of the latest dists  like:

`<script src="/myapp/javascript/rx.all.js"></script>`

I get Rx undefined.  What is the nuance occurring between these two different ways of reference.

What is the surefire way to import rxjs for client-side use?   Is this the likely cause of the debounce not working (not having the full lib)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use debounceTime for this, not debounce. debounce takes a function parameter which must determine dynamically the debounce time, whereas debounceTime can be used exactly as you state:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // setup an observable
    submission = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#submitbutton"), "click").map(
        event => {
            return "justsomeusername";
        }
    );

    submission
        .debounceTime(500)
        .concatMap(username => {
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
                $.get(
                    "{{ site.serveraddress }}/checkuser?&username=" + username
                )
            ).catch(() => Rx.Observable.empty());
        })
        .subscribe(rval => {
            console.log(rval);
        });
});
```

If you wanted to use debounce, you'd do something like this:

```
    submission
        .debounce((val) => {
            // Add whatever logic for determining the right
            // debounce time for the value entered by the 
            // user, in this case, simply returning a hard
            // coded 500 which will do exactly the same as
            // debounceTime(500)
            return 500;
        })
        .concatMap(username => {
            // ... snip ...
        });
});
```

It doesn't look like there is any problem with how you are importing RxJS - although I would advise if you're just starting with RxJS to go to v6 as it changes how a lot of things are done with operators like debounce and concatMap - it's a pain to change it all later so better to make the change when you're just starting!

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for that explanation. I changed my import to https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.js as per github and it leads to 6.2.2 which is fine but then I get " Uncaught TypeError: rxjs.Observable.fromEvent is not a function"  so this now seems to be a namespace import issue.   Are you able to get a simple observable established with a map using that import?   It seems the namespace from 5 to 6 changed from Rx to rxjs.

Comment: Lots of things with V6 are different - they changed most things from methods to functions. So Observable.fromEvent becomes just fromEvent(), Observable.fromPromise becomes just from(), etc. The operators all need to be piped now, so e.g. submission.pipe(debounceTime(500), concatMap(...))... Google for rxjs v5 to v6 migration for better guides than I can provide in a comment :)